# C# Regex Check For Control Panel

Tags: c#, regex, controls, panel, minecraft

I have this problem in C#..
I am trying to make a control panel for Minecraft Servers.
I have the console output and all those things in the control panel and it works.
Now I have like an online player box, but the code behind it isn't working..
I am trying to check for something like this: [11:49:43 INFO]: JonasC[/127.0.0.1:51292] logged in
but then with Regex and it should like have a time in the begin and the name and ip address should also be variable..
I have this code right now but it doesn't work..

```
#region Test for join
try
{
    Regex TestRegex = new Regex(@"[0-9\-]{10}\ ([0-9:]{8})\ \[INFO\]\ ([^\ ]*)\ [^\]]*\]\ (logged\ in)");
    if (TestRegex.IsMatch(AText))
    {
        MessageLogAddition = "";

        string[] Matches = TestRegex.Split(AText);
        MessageLogAddition += Matches[1] + " ";
        MessageLogAddition += Matches[2] + " ";
        MessageLogAddition += "joined.";

        ConnectedPlayersListBox.Items.Add(Matches[2].Trim());

        if (!AllPlayersListBox.Items.Contains(Matches[2].Trim()))
        {
            AllPlayersListBox.Items.Add(Matches[2].Trim());
        }
    }
}
catch
{
}
#endregion
```

All help is appreciated!
This panel is open source.
The code is located at: http://coded.ddns.info/dl/MCSC_Source.zip

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What about this:

```
var TestRegex = new Regex(@"\[(?<time>.+) INFO]: (?<name>.+)\[(?<ip>.+)\] logged in");
```

You can also then reference the named groups like this:

```
var match = reg.Match(AText);
var timeJoined = match.Groups["time"];
var userName = match.Groups["name"];
var ip = match.Groups["ip"];
```